# Opening fstream with file with Unicode file name under Windows using non-MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, unicode, wide-api

I need to open a file as std::fstream (or actually any other std::ostream) when file name is "Unicode" file name.

Under MSVC I have **non-standard** extension `std::fstream::open(wchar_t const *,...)`? What can I do with other compilers like GCC (most important) and probably Borland compiler.

I know that CRTL provides `_wfopen` but it gives C `FILE *` interface instead of io-streams, maybe there is a non-standard way to create io-stream from `FILE *`? Is there any `boost::ifstream` with MSVC like extension for Windows?

Comment: You can't. On Mac OS X it was decided that the POSIX file api's - and hence std::fstream - would all take utf-8. 
In environments where there are not platform specific extentions (such as gcc and bc on windows (actually, they might have their own extensions, but that would be outside of the POSIX standard)) the c & c++ runtime functions cannot be expected to reliably access the filesystem given files with non ascii characters in their name.

Comment: @Chris I have no problems with library that supports UTF-8 - it is perfect for me. The issue that Windows does not support UTF-8

Comment: a hackish workaround for MinGW is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524821/opening-stream-via-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no easy solution.

You need to create your own stream buffer that uses `_wfopen` under the hood. You can use for this for example `boost::iostream`

Comment: *_wfopen* is windows specific, guess boost resolves according to platform?!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065142/9437799

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, there's no standard way to do that, although C++0x (1x?) promises to do that. Until then, you properly assumed that a solution can be found in Boost, however, the library you're searching for is [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html).

Boost.Filesystem internally uses wide strings by default for its universal path system, so there are no unicode problems in this regard.

Comment: Do you have a reference for C++0X?  I remember discussions but no conclusion and I found nothing in the latest draft.

Comment: The problem is the `boost::filesystem` does not supports wpath under MinGW/GCC because boost configuration defines `BOOST_NO_STD_WSTRING` for some reason (even wide strings work quite well under mingw)

Comment: I've searched a little more and found this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#454, apparently no solution before library TR2.

Comment: I think it is not good solution to add `wchar_t`. I think that MS CRTL just should support UTF-8 strings instead. Windows is only operating system that uses wide API for core parts.

Comment: @art the issue is that windows supported unicode before utf8 was invented and wide was the best choice at that time. The die is now cast.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the Unicode filename to a `char*` string using something like `wcstombs()` or `WideCharToMultiByte()` (which gives you far more control over the codepages involved).

Then use the converted filename to open the file.

Comment: File name includes unicode characters that may not be represented in current locale codepage (i.e. Hebrew characters can't be represented in Latin1 8-bit locale), also Windows does not support UTF-8 code pages. So no, this does not work.

Comment: covers most of the practical use cases with special characters, where that MS-`MultiByte` actually has been ANSI