# How does MSVC's STL open an fstream with a wide string filename?

Tags: c++, unicode, fstream, widestring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening fstream with file with Unicode file name under Windows using non-MSVC compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316672/opening-fstream-with-file-with-unicode-file-name-under-windows-using-non-msvc-com)

I have been trying to find a *simple* way to open a file with non-ASCII characters in its filename in Windows with GCC. Microsoft's STL provides `wstring` overloads for the `fstream` classes, but Standard C++ does not, because `wchar_t´ isn't well-defined.

I'm looking for a way to open a `fstream` when given a `std::wstring` for a filename, in Standard C++ and Win32 API.

I do **not** want to create my own streambuf subclass that takes a `std::wstring` and imitates `fstream`. I **do** need to imitate the `fstream::open(const std::wstring &)` (or whatever it's declared as) function, so I can open weirdly named files without a hitch.

I have already thought of using the short DOS 8.3 filenames, but the GetShortPathName takes and outputs wide strings, unusable for the STL constructor/open function. I do have methods in place to convert to different codepages, so perhaps converting the wide string to local codepage will give the correct 8-bit string that allows me to open an `fstream`?

Comment: @raj: oh, yes, I forgot to mention, Boost, as good as it may be, is a bit too intrusive here for me to use it. I need a `std::fstream+std::wstring` combined with the Win32 API. The MSVC STL does it, I just don't know how :(

Comment: Have you tried using WideCharToMultiByte and passing the result to gcc fstream::open ? Only works if the wstring can be expressed correctly in the current local code page

Comment: @raj: if the current local codepage cannot represent the filename, what would the filename look like in Explorer? Or if printed by the `dir` command? How would you tell `delete` to remove the file? Wouldn't you always need to do that through some local codepage? I find this frustrating, that it  is seemingly possible, but no one seems to know how.

Comment: Internally all Win32API that takes strings have two versions.  Example OpenFileA and OpenFileW. OpenFileW takes the wchar_t version that fstream::open(const std::wstring &) uses.

Comment: Well, using my default local codepage 850, Saving a file with a name containing the Euro symbol €, produces question marks instead of that symbol. When I try to enter a € symbol, I get a question mark. When I try to open an `fstream` with a question mark instead of the Euro symbol, it fails. There seems to be absolutely no way to work this out...

Comment: @Raj: What would I use to link `OpenFileW` to `std::ifstream`?

Comment: The MSVC STL ships with source for both the STL and the CRT. So why not just step through what it does to understand how to do this?

Comment: "but Standard C++ does not, because `wchar_t` isn't well-defined." While it's true that several properties of `wchar_t` are implementation defined, I find it far more likely that this is simply a historical oversight like how iostreams have no knowledge of `std::string`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: 99% right. Not an oversight, time pressure. It's quite likely that a well-written proposal would have made it.