# How to tell setup.py to use Visual Studio

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm building a Python extension module on Windows. The extension module is written in C++. When I call `setup.py bdist` then setup.py uses MinGW to compile the C++ code. Is there any way I can tell setup.py to use MSVS 2008 instead?

(Why do I want to do this? This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316672/opening-fstream-with-file-with-unicode-file-name-under-windows-using-non-msvc-co) is one reason.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
setup.py build --compiler=msvc
setup.py bdist_egg
```

Comment: No, I get the error message "error: option --compiler not recognized".

Comment: `python setup.py build --compiler=msvc` (or `build_ext`) has usually done the trick for me, but YMMV.

Comment: And after "setup.py build --compiler=msvc" I just run "setup.py bdist" to create the distribution package. Right?

Comment: What if there's several version of Visual Studio installed (e.g. VS2017, VS2019). Then how can I specify VS2017 instead of VS2019?

Comment: @HaxtraZ, I have this problem too where I have installed `Visual studio 2010` beside `2017` and know I don't know how make the `setup.py` to use 2017 one.

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi As a workaround, in setup.py we can invoke cmake. It is easy to specify compiler in cmake, just specify the generator. You may refer to this (written by me) https://github.com/Sanster/text_renderer/blob/d096c3b1ff8089371a47da4e76e85d041c7bb44a/libs/gpu/setup.py#L81